# How to know if Copy/Pasted Cells Contains first column?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I know which cells a Pasted or Copy/Pasted cells contains. 
 
 **I want to let the user copy and paste cells when the copied range contains any of the cells from the first column `Column A`,**  If not then return a msgbox error (but I dont know how to do this with the Worksheet Change event.

**Expected Results:**
 When copy/Pasted does not contains at least one cell from `Column A` (FirstColumn) then returns a error, but if contains one from columnA than copy/pasted is allowed (how can i achieve this)?

Comment: Do you have any code that you can share with us?

Comment: Unfortunately, excel does not provide a 'before worksheet change' event, only an 'on worksheet changed' event.  So, while it is possible to determine that a user has changed a cell in column A, it is not possible to intercept the paste event and prevent column A from being changed.  I suggest you look into 'locked cells' and worksheet security to guarantee that a user can't change particular regions of a worksheet.

Comment: Its not possible like when he paste (you can probably know what got pasted (by saying this i mean what was the cells/range he pasted to determine if got column A on pasted cells)? And if the paste does not contains the conditions you want i was thinking just doing and application.undo + msgbox(error...) ?

Comment: sure, you can do that.  Use the INTERSECT method to see if the TARGET range overlaps with column A.

Comment: @RyanB. It is possible actually, I'll find code to share for it.

Comment: With `worksheet_selectionchange` on sheet whenever its triggered define `usedRowsCount = Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` and `usedColumnsCount = Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count`. On a worksheet change then you can compare the count against the value again and if something was added or removed, mark it in some way. If he wanted to check if the value was from column A, then he can use the range of his selection and see if it intersects with `A:A`, and if so allow a paste and update the value.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this, assuming the user must select the data before copy.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim a As Long
a = Selection.Cells.Count
If Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("error you must copy data from 'A' column")
else 
MsgBox "you have selected " & (a) & "cells" 
End If
End Sub
```

place it on a worksheet object of your vba project where is stored the data to copy
hope this helps